# Bootstrap carousel prev/next issue

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-5

Basically what I'm trying to do is go left/right pictures but instead my page moves slightly lower
I'm even trying to follow an instructor on how to get this done but there must be a piece of code I'm missing

```
    <div id="testimonial-carousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="false">
      <div class="carousel-inner">
        <div class="carousel-item active">
          <h2>I no longer have to sniff other dogs for love. I've found the hottest Corgi on TinDog. Woof.</h2>
          <img class="testimonial-image" src="images/dog-img.jpg" alt="dog-profile">
          <em>Pebbles, New York</em>
        </div>
        <div class="carousel-item">
          <h2 class="testimonial-text">My dog used to be so lonely, but with TinDog's help, they've found the love of
            their life. I think.</h2>
          <img class="testimonial-image" src="images/lady-img.jpg" alt="lady-profile">
          <em>Beverly, Illinois</em>
        </div>
      </div>
      <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#testimonial-carousel" role="button" data-slide="prev">
        <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon"></span>
        <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
      </a>
      <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#testimonial-carousel" role="button" data-slide="next">
        <span class="carousel-control-next-icon"></span>
        <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
      </a>
    </div>
```

I wanted to be able to view pictures manually (by clicking on them) with the previous/next buttons

Comment: Refused to apply style from 'https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js' because its MIME type ('application/javascript') is not a supported stylesheet MIME type, and strict MIME checking is enabled.

just noticed that im also getting this error on chrome elements

Answer (score 0):

Problem was that my referred (href) was inside link instead of a script

```
 <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
```

I must have accidentally replaced this somehow along the way when I moved folders (because I mostly refer links and don't use local library.)